# Powershell Hashtable with multiple values to HTML

Tags: html, powershell, hashtable

Trying to convert Hashtable with multiple values  to HTML

```
$myHashTable=@{}
$servers=@("server1","server2")

foreach($srv in $servers){
    $myHashTable.$srv = @() 
    $myHashTable.$srv += Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName $srv | where {$_.name -like "M*"}
}

$myHashTable | ConvertTo-html -Fragment -> no data in table

$myHashTable | ConvertTo-Json does works fine.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `$myHashTable.Values |ConvertTo-Html`

Comment: It's converting the *hashtable* object to html, not the entries it contains. Try ```$myHashTable.GetEnumerator() | ConvertTo-Html``` and see if that looks any better. If not, you might need to convert your hashtable to an array of PSCustomObjects instead (or just build an array of them inside your ```foreach```).